# react when refresh clear local storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to store data in the local storage, but the data got cleared every time the webpage refresh.

```
const accounts = () => {
  let list = localStorage.getItem("Account List");
  if (list) {
    return JSON.parse(list);
  } else {
    return [];
  }
};

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState(accounts());

  const [accountList, setAccountList] = useState([]);
  const addAccount = (id) => {
    if (accountList.find((data) => data === id)) {
      setAccountList([...accountList]);
    } else {
      setAccountList([...accountList, id]);
    }
  };

 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("Account List", JSON.stringify(accountList));
  }, [accountList];

...

}
```

The code is working as I expected, but I wasn't expected the data to get removed. Is there a problem with the code? Appreciated any kinda response.

Edit: I'm using the wrong state, I should use the `accountList` state instead of `account`

```
 const [account, setAccount] = useState("");
 const [accountList, setAccountList] = useState(accounts());
```

Comment: Is it delete the localstorage key or it clear the value?

Comment: Why do you use an empty array here: `const [accountList, setAccountList] = useState([]);` ? Shouldn't that be `const [accountList, setAccountList] = useState(accounts());` ? What's the purpose of `const [account, setAccount] = useState(accounts());`? You don't seem to use `account`/`setAccount` anywhere.

Comment: when the page refresh, `accountList` is assigned the initial value of `[]` and `useEffect` sets "Account List" with an empty array

Comment: "The code is working as I expected, but I wasn't expected the data to get removed." So... the code ***isn't*** working as expected? Which state are you trying to persist to localStorage and which are you wanting to "hydrate" from localStorage?

Comment: @FelixKling thank you, I made a mistake there

Comment: Have you still an issue or have you resolved your discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

Local storage in some cases can make you various problems that you have to deal with. More modern solution for preserving globally state of some important variables is Store, here is [Redux for example](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-conceptshttps://)

Comment: Since redux is stored in memory only I think OP will still have an issue with state disappearing after a page reload. 